# Имитировать клик и вставку ссылки на форму input с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу имитировать клик и вставку ссылки в форму `input` с помощью javascript.

*(Есть сайты, которые при вставке ссылки на видео показывают подробную информацию, а через код просто вставляет, подробная информация не выскакивает)*

Пробовал делать так c библиотекой jQuery:

```
$("input").val("111"); 
jQuery("body *").blur();
jQuery("body *").focus();
```

и т.п. фокусировки, но не реагирует. Что еще можно добавить, чтобы все было также, как если бы делали через мышку?

Comment: Разные сайты по разному будут обрабатывать вставку. Кто-то может на `blur` реагиировать, кто-то на `input`, а кто-то на `paste`. В общем, надо смотреть на конкретный сайт.

Comment: вконтакте или одноклассниках есть кнопка добавления видео со стороннего сайта (youtube, rutube), когда вставляю через мышку открывается вся информация о видео, а через код просто вставляет ссылку, а информация не выходит, пока с настоящей мышкой не нажмем по этой области, где ссылка

Comment: Ага, значит с сайтом определились. Вот и надо посмотреть, какие события связаны с этой областью. Посмотреть можете в хроме `DevTools->Elements->Event Listeners`